# sfGuardPlugin in Symfony 1.4 - install - no release available for plugin

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I can' t install sfGuardPlugin in symfony 1.4
**I use command**:

```
symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin
```

Then i get: No release available for plugin "sfGuardPlugin" in state ""

**When I use**:

```
php symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin --release=4.0.2
```

I get: Unable to get download information for plugin "sfGuardPlugin | 4.0.2 | ": "" is not a valid state

**If i try for example release=4.0 i get**: Unable to get dependencies information for plugin "sfGuardPlugin": File http://plugins.symfony-project.org:80/REST/r/sfguardplugin/deps.4.0.txt not valid (received: HTTP/1.0 404 Version does not exist) (use --force-license to force installation)

I use MAMP, OS X Lion and PHP 5.3.6.

How i can install sfGuard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! That was problem with PEAR. PEAR is installed, but there is no shortcut for it.

> sudo emacs -rw /etc/path

and add path to Your MAMP/PHP bin folder. For me is:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5/bin

I used before(so i have php5):

> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php; ln -s php5.3.6 php5

[For older MAMP version, there is only one php folder, no two]

Now after restart terminal You can just type: pear in each place.

Now i can use: php symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin and it works :)

If Your pear don' t works correct try delete pear config file from path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5/conf
```

I hope it will help someone.